# GET запросы с помощью ссылок в PHP

Tags: php, html

Дан массив:

$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
Сделайте так, чтобы с помощью GET запроса можно было вывести любой элемент этого массива. Для этого с помощью цикла foreach сделайте ссылку для каждого элемента массива.

```
<?php $arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; 
foreach($arr as $elem) { ?>
<a href="?<?=$elem?>=<?=$elem?>"><?=$elem?></a>
<?php } ?><br>
<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>
```

По заданию требуется вывести соответствующий элемент массива по нажатию на ссылку, но у меня получилось только вывести его вместе с массивом, подскажите как решить, чтобы было красиво.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял ваше задание, но попытаюсь:

1. Надо бы проверить есть-ли такой элемент в массиве, для начала.
2. Ну и собственно вывод.

Пробуйте:

```
<?php 
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
if (isset($_GET['element'])) {
  $element = $_GET['element'];
  if (in_array($element, $arr)) {
    echo "Выбранный элемент: $element";
  } else {
    echo "Выбранный элемент не найден";
  }
}
foreach($arr as $elem) { 
  echo "<a href='?element=$elem'>$elem</a>";
}
```

ну или по Вашей методике вывод ссылок:

```
<?php 
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
if (isset($_GET['element'])) {
  $element = $_GET['element'];
  if (in_array($element, $arr)) {
    echo "Выбранный элемент: $element";
  } else {
    echo "Выбранный элемент не найден";
  }
}
foreach($arr as $elem) { 
?>
  <a href="?element=<?=$elem?>"><?=$elem?></a>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, кажется начинаю понимать как это должно работать! Не подскажете, где бы я мог почитать об этом более подробно? В том учебнике, по которому я учусь тема вообще не раскрыта. Ваш способ вывода ссылок выгляди гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Не за что. Удачи Вам!